# How can I get Vista to recognise my harddrive?

Tags: windows-vista, external-hard-drive, formatting

I have Windows Vista Home Premium with SP2. I recently bought a Maxtor 1Tb external harddrive. I started to format it (FAT32) but it took hours. I left it running overnight - when I came back it was only about 30% done.

So I thought that I would restart using Quick Format. I stopped it in the correct way but now Vista does not recognise the harddrive. Specifically, I can eject it using "Safely Remove Hardware" but I cannot see it in Windows Explorer, nor can I reformat it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using disk management:

1. Right click on `computer` from the `start menu` and select `manage`.
2. Then on the left side, click on "*disk management*" and see if you drive is there:

   [image]

You can also format the drive from there as well.  Also consider using a NTFS partition.  I believe that is better for larger hard drives on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ridiculous but a few minutes after posting the question I found the answer:

Control Panel -> Administrative Tools (classic view) -> Computer Management -> Disk Management.

From there I just right-clicked on the disk and got it recognised. Quick format took about 2 seconds!